# Do ThunderCats and SilverHawks share the same universe?

Tags: crossovers, thundercats, silverhawks

During a forum discussion, someone mentioned that [**ThunderCats**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThunderCats) and [**SilverHawks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilverHawks) took place in the same universe. The only thing I was able to find was that SilverHawks villain [Mon*Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilverHawks#Villains) briefly appeared in the background of a [ThunderCats (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThunderCats_(2011_TV_series)) episode. Since the remake was fond of 80's homages and easter eggs, though, this was probably just a quick reference for fans.

Granted, there are some similarities in both character design and technology, but otherwise I don't remember seeing anything that would indicate they were in the same galaxy, or even the same fictional universe.

Although... come to think of it, Mon*Star DOES look a bit like other Thunderrans we've seen:

[image]

**Beyond this one reference in the TC remake, is there any indication that the events of ThunderCats and SilverHawks take place in a shared universe?**

Comment: @MrLister - in the show, it's pronounced as "Mon-star".

Comment: @MrLister - LOL, try "Mon Star".

Comment: @MrLister : Yes, it is pronounced "Mon Star".  The intended out-of-universe effect is that it sounds almost like "monster".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The only "evidence" is Mon*Star's cameo in *Thundercats* (2011).

As you have already noted, a character closely resembling Mon*Star briefly appears on a screen in the episode "Legacy" of the 2011 *Thundercats* series.  Depending on how strongly one interprets this, this could be solid evidence that both *Thundercats* and *SilverHawks* share the same fictional universe.  The *MTV Geek* column on the MTV web site went in this direction with [their interpretation](http://geek-news.mtv.com/2011/08/30/new-thundercats-silverhawks-tigersharks-reveal-episode-7-legacy/):

> This clip CONFIRMS the inclusion of both the SilverHawks and TigerSharks in the new ThunderCats universe!  We can clearly see SilverHawks nemesis Mon*Star and TigerSharks hero Mako in the clip below.

[image]

Here is Mon*Star as he appeared in the original *SilverHawks* series:

[image]

Personally, I would back off from going as far as the *MTV Geek* assessment, for the following reasons:

- the *Thundercats* remake has a significant nostalgia factor, as you have mentioned already in the question, and this could be an easter egg for out-of-universe effect only;
- we do not have independent confirmation that the image on the screen in "Legacy"
  is definitively Mon*Star, despite the resemblance;
- it could be a new character with an appearance inspired by Mon*Star.

## Upshot

While there is no evidence to rule out that *Thundercats* and *SilverHawks* occupy the same universe, there are also no independently-verifiable statements that say that they do.

Of course, the two original series were made by the same studio and shared writers and many of the same voice actors.  It is therefore natural that the two series would share some common themes, and the shows were always regarded as "siblings" in a sense.  That's likely the best that we can say.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there was an episode that the SilverHawks actually flew across the Remains of Thundera on known as the homeworld of the thundercats.

Comment: Which episode was that?

Comment: @Kyser - if you can find which episode that was, or maybe post a screenshot of the scene you're referring to, I'm sure you'll get some upvotes on this answer.

Comment: If is true that the Third Planet is Earth in the very far future (as you can find here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/did-the-original-thundercats-cartoon-take-place-on-earth), there is no way that the Silver Hawks and the Thundercats could exist at the same time